# For which value of the parameter $k$ are the inequalities $\frac{x+2k}{3}≤ {x+1 }$ and $x ≥ 3$ equivalent?

Tags: inequality

I am not very good at solving inequalities with parameters. How do the parameters fit into the inequality and how do you solve them?

Comment: Well, can you multiply by $3$ and isolate $x$ in first inequality ? for which $k$ does $2x\ge 6$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$\frac{ (x+2k)}{3}≤ x+1 $$
$$\implies 3x+3\ge x+ 2k$$
$$ \implies 2x\ge 2k-3$$
$$\implies x\ge \frac{2k-3}{2}$$
For  answer 
$$\implies  \frac{2k-3}{2}=3  $$
$$\implies k=\frac{9}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have :
$$\frac{x+2k}{3}\leq x+1$$
$$\Rightarrow x+2k\leq 3x+3$$
$$\Rightarrow 2k\leq 2x+3$$
Rewriting for clarity:
$$2x+3 \geq 2k$$
$$x\geq \frac{2k-3}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{2k-3}{2}=3$$
$$\Rightarrow k=4.5$$